# Socket with IOS cocos2dx

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, cocos2d-x

I need to build an game use Socket to connect multi device.
I have a problem when i try to create socket on cocos2dx.

```
void AcceptCallBack(
                    CFSocketRef socket,
                    CFSocketCallBackType type,
                    CFDataRef address,
                    const void *data,
                    void *info)
{
    CFReadStreamRef readStream = NULL;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream = NULL;
    CFIndex bytes;
    UInt8 buffer[128];
    UInt8 recv_len = 0, send_len = 0;

    /* The native socket, used for various operations */
    CFSocketNativeHandle sock = *(CFSocketNativeHandle *) data;

    /* The punch line we stored in the socket context */
    char *punchline = info;

    /* Create the read and write streams for the socket */
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket(kCFAllocatorDefault, sock,
                                 &readStream, &writeStream);

    if (!readStream || !writeStream) {
        close(sock);
        fprintf(stderr, "CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket() failed\n");
        return;
    }

    CFReadStreamOpen(readStream);
    CFWriteStreamOpen(writeStream);

    /* Wait for the client to finish sending the joke; wait for newline */
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    while (!strchr((char *) buffer, '\n') && recv_len < sizeof(buffer)) {
        bytes = CFReadStreamRead(readStream, buffer + recv_len,
                                 sizeof(buffer) - recv_len);
        if (bytes < 0) {
            //       fprintf(stderr, "CFReadStreamRead() failed: %d\n", bytes);
            close(sock);
            return;
        }
        //   NSLog(@"Read: %d", bytesRead);
        NSLog(@"buffer: %s", buffer);
        recv_len += bytes;
    }

    /* Send the punchline */
    while (send_len < (strlen(punchline+1))) {
        if (CFWriteStreamCanAcceptBytes(writeStream)) {
            bytes = CFWriteStreamWrite(writeStream,
                                       (unsigned char *) punchline + send_len,
                                       (strlen((punchline)+1) - send_len) );
            if (bytes < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "CFWriteStreamWrite() failed\n");
                close(sock);
                return;
            }
            send_len += bytes;
        }
        close(sock);
        CFReadStreamClose(readStream);
        CFWriteStreamClose(writeStream);
        return;
    }
}
```

Everything is ok when i run it on Ios Application (Default setting by Xcode when create new project)

But when i copy that source code to project create by Cocos2dx.
I got an error at this line:

```
char *punchline = info;
```

Error message:

```
Can not initialize a variable of type 'char *' with an Ivalue of type 'void *'
```

I don't know which setting should be change to run it.
Thanks.

Comment: If you are 100% certain that info is a pointer to char then you simply need to cast it (also better to use const): const char* punchline = (const char*)info;

Comment: Thanks. But i don't know why i don't got that error when i run it in Ios Application.